# PHP - Simple and Neat Way to Check if..else Condition

Tags: php

I have 3 tables to queries and check if there is a value on one of the three table using a same variable. At the moment, I can think of is to use `if else condition` to check. Below are the example,

```
if (isset($post_val)) {
    $var= /* mysql queries table 1 */ 
}

if (empty($var)) {
    $var= /* mysql queries table 2 */ 

    if (empty($var)) {
        $var= /* mysql queries table 3 */ 
    }
}
```

Is there are more shorter or neat way to do it.

> Update Codes

Actually, I am using a plugin from wordpress that is `CFDB`. My actual code will be.

```
if (isset($vehicle_no)) {
    $location = do_shortcode('[cfdb-value form="season parking form_copy" filter="your-platno=' . $vehicle_no . '"');
}

if (empty($location)) {
     $location = do_shortcode('[cfdb-value form="season parking form" filter="your-platno=' . $vehicle_no . '"');

     if (empty($location)) {
         $location = do_shortcode('[cfdb-value form="Season Register 2017" filter="your-platno=' . $vehicle_no . '"');
     }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [`UNION`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unions-clause.htm) might be useful in your case.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for the idea and link. Will look through it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I update my question

Answer (score 1):

You could just union the tables together and then search that one. i.e.

```
 if (isset($post_val)) {
         $var= /* mysql queries table 1 UNION table2 UNION table3 */ ;
 }
```

Comment: Without seeing the database structure to see if you could get the three values in a single query with joins, UNION seems to be the best solution.

Comment: @G3D thanks for the help. I update my question for the actual code